# Robot Framework - Syntax errors when comparing list to an empty list

Tags: robotframework

Why is the following statement giving syntax error in Robot Framework? Thanks in advance.

```
@{hidden_routes_1} =    Create List    222.2.1.0    12.250.2.2    222.2.2.0
Run Keyword If   '@{hidden_routes_1}'=='@{EMPTY}'   Log To Console    Lists are equal
```

### Errors:

Evaluating expression ''['222.2.1.0', '12.250.2.2', '222.2.2.0']'=='[]'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax:

```
'@{hidden_routes_1}'=='@{EMPTY}'
```

reads as "dump the lists as strings, surround them with single quotes and compare. A string representation of a list is:

```
['222.2.1.0', '12.250.2.2', '222.2.2.0']
```

- the members are already with single quotes. Thus the one you've put as an opening is closed by the first for the list members - and this produces syntax error expression.

For this particular usage to work, surround them in the evaluated condition with triple quotes - the python way to mark a string as containing newlines and (arbitrary) quotes:

```
Run Keyword If  """@{hidden_routes_1}"""=="""@{EMPTY}"""  Log To Console    Lists are equal
```

Or better, use targeted keywords for doing such checks, like `Should Be Empty` or `Lists Should Be Equal`.